# How I can move the images like in this video?

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, video

I want to know how I can do this moving animation with images. What is this effect is called? Here is the video that has this "**animation**":

***https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jq5qyFrO-RU***

Comment: Possibly more on-topic in the video production community?

Comment: Also, I think you would gain by providing timestamps of which part of the video you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called a parallax scroll. Or more accurately parallax move in this case. since it is moving in several directions at once. Its still the same effect. Basically you have several layers on top that react to movement at different speeds/ or if your setup is 3d are at different distances form camera.